# Confidential data showing on google search. How to disable?

Tags: codeigniter

I  developed a helpdesk system in our company and put on web.

One of my colleague reported to me that his employee info is shown on the Google search when he tried to search for his name. There's a module where the system asks for an employee number when applying for service request and retrieve some basic employee info.

How can I disable this? Is it something to do with SEO? I don't have enough idea.

I am using Codeigniter as my framework.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Generally, a good idea is just not serve pages to unauthenticaed users (e.g. the Google crawler).

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it @PaulProgrammer?

Comment: That's not an easy thing to "just do".  You have to design with user roles, logins and security in mind from the beginning.  And then, once you have that, you can just route any queries to by unauthenticated requests to a 403 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CodeIgniter view files inside head add Meta tag

> meta name="robots" content="noindex"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
(…)
</head>
<body>(…)</body>
</html>
```

The robots meta tag in the above example instructs search engines not to show the page in search results. For detailed info please check this documentation by Google.
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_meta_tag

Comment: already added it into a specific page which shows from the google search but doesn't work

Comment: It will work. Next time when the Google crawl will visit your site it will see the meta tag and update the search engine to not index those pages. Now In search result when you click the arrow down of your page you can see the cached version where you will see the snapshot of your page, this is the time the crawler visited and indexed the pages.

Comment: Oh I see. I keep on refreshing google. Maybe I'll wait for some hours and observe if you're right.

Comment: No it doesn't work this way. You might need to wait for days to see the changes as Google will update its search database index and only after that you will see the changes. You can read more about it here https://hoist.digital/content/blog/how-often-does-google-update-its-search-results

Comment: Thanks and noted. But do I still need to put robots.txt on my root?

Comment: Robot.txt file helps govern rules that you want to tell the Web crawel what to index or what to not. If you want not to index any pages you can do that in robot.txt file by adding this
User-agent: * Disallow: / . You can read more about it over here https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt